# Lxqt application menu categories mixed up and contains duplicates after login to openbox

Tags: appmenu, openbox, lxqt

I logged into OpenBox just to see how it was and then logged back into Lxqt now i have duplicates of half the things and in random categories.

Comment: You need to mention more details of your system. Duplicates entries in one's menus are common when you have more than one desktop environment. What do you have in `/usr/share/xsessions`?

Comment: in /usr/share/applications there are duplicates, i am not sure how to change the categories for LXQt.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions`.

Comment: It fixed its self now...